# Свой css для сайтов в браузере

Tags: html, css, браузер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, расширение или что-то подобное, что сможет сохранить мои личные CSS для сторонних сайтов. К примеру, у ВКонтакте `background: #edeef0;`, а я хочу поменять на свой цвет, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы дописывались стили через `!important` или `inline`.

Comment: может [stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)

Comment: https://userstyles.org

Comment: @diraria напиши пожалуйста как ответ, что бы я отметил. спасибо.

Comment: @Air первый вариант меня вполне устроил. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный напишите лучше сами, а я плюсик поставлю) я просто ни разу не пользовался этим расширением

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Расширения для браузера - [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe/related)

Ответ дан пользователем: [diraria](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227016/diraria).

Answer (score 3):

Использую [User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld/support?hl=ru) для Хрома.
Шикарная штука

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/216257)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, название расширения является ответом так же, как название библиотеки.

Answer (score 2):

Если требуются только стили без скриптов, то подойдёт [User CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb) - можно настраивать стили для конкретных сайтов, включать или выключать расширение. Использую его для некоторый модификаций SO.

К сожалению, это расширение добавляет стили только после загрузки страницы. В связи с [сезоном шляп](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6552/178988) пришлось сменить его на другое.

Answer (score 1):

Расширение [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=ru) добавляет стили немедленно, не дожидаясь загрузки страницы, что очень удобно в случаях, когда требуется немедленное применение стилей ([пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6552/178988)).

Только надо переключить режим редактирования в Edit CSS:

[image: скриншот настроек]